# HTML save .txt at local server

Tags: javascript, html

I found a code that grab the info and save in a .txt file. But when i click "SAVE" button, it downloads the file to my own computer instead of save it in the local server.

I followed the steps from Red Stapler's video on YT about FileSaver.js source.

```
<script src="/tree/app/FileSaver.js"></script>   

$("#save-btn").click(function() {
    var blob = new Blob([INFO], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    saveAs(blob, "model.txt");
});
```

I need to save the file at the local server and overwrite it everytime i press the button.

Comment: to save it on the server you will need to use php not javascript

Comment: The way you are using JavaScript is for client side. You must use another back-end language to save a file to a server. I suggest you using PHP, it's the easiest to overcome what you are trying to achieve, also the easiest and cheap to host.

Comment: You're asking about saving a file to a server, but not giving any information of your server. Can you please at least add the server type and the used language?

Comment: It's a jupyter server with a UI in html and a python script to run an AI to recognize pictures with Deep learning.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a language executed on the client. If you'd allow each and every client to write to your server it would be very unsafe.

I suggest you make a simple PHP file on your webserver which has the chmod 755 permission and then let javascript send a POST-request to this php file which then creates the associated file.

Comment: Apache/PHP is not the only solution for a local server, OP didn't tell what they're using.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify that the client should not be creating files on a webhost, as that would be leading to unsafe cases.

Comment: Not safe? I upload files all the time to different servers. It's just, that JS can't do it alone, some back-end code is needed.

Comment: OP's using only javascript, if the case he only wanted to use javascript to upload files to a webserver you would need to set permission to 777. This leads to very unsafe cases.

Comment: But if they're building a local app with Electra for example, then denying writing permissions sounds odd ..? Web was not mentioned at all. The lesson of the story is, that you should not answer unclear and ambiguous questions, there's simply not enough information to give a reasonable answer to this question.

Comment: My server will be used internaly only, not open to the web. There is only one terminal that an user can access and save the file.